# How to spawn an animated div with creation/destruction conditions

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a series of divs that slowly fade into existence and float a distance across their container. Once a floating div (floater) goes outside the container/off-screen it reappears where it was spawned and fades back in again, looping forever.

I have successfully created the basic animation, but I don't know of an efficient way to have several divs spawned and float/follow each other to the edge of the container.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Here is what I have so far for my single div animation:

```
function floaters()
{
$('.floater').each(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, {queue: false, duration: 5000}) ;
    $(this).animate({'left': '-=652'}, 2000, 'linear', function(){
        $(this).css('left', '622px') ;
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.0') ;
        floaters() ;
    }) ;
})
}
```

I am unsure if 'each' is what I should be using or not.

---

You can see what I have done so far here and what I'm trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y73TZ/

I basically want a series of boxes to follow each other and loop once each one reaches the end of the page, exactly the same as this one box does, but each with a random starting distance between them.

---

@r0m4n Kind of what I wanted, but I want each box to start at the same location with a delay  between them so their is an even amount of space between each box and no more than say 8 boxes present at one time. What would be the adjustments to the script to achieve this?

---

I have redone the script in the hopes that it will better explain what I'm trying to do. I have used setInterval instead as it gives me better control of the events I want to happen at certain points in the animation:

```
var creationTimer ;
var moveTimer ;
function floaters()
{
var firstTime = 1 ;
moveTimer = setInterval(function(){
    $('.floater').each(function(){
        var pos = $(this).position() ;
        $(this).css('left', (pos.left-2)+'px') ;
        if(pos.left < -32 || firstTime == 1)
        {
            firstTime = 0 ;
            $(this).css('left', '620px') ;
            $(this).hide() ;
            $(this).show(500);
        }
        if(pos.left < 500 && pos.left > 450)
        {
            clearTimeout(creationTimer) ;
            creationTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#latest').append('<div class="floater"></div>') ;
            }, 1000)
            clearInterval(moveTimer);
        }
    })
}, 50)
}
```

At the point where clearInterval(moveTimer) is called, I want a new div to appear and follow the preceeding box. I want that cycle to repeat X amount of times. I hope I am explaining this well enough. Thanks for your help so far.

---

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you set the animation up in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see your current animation and understand what you're going for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to do something. Sorry if I don't reuse your code. I hope you can configure as you want.

```
var distance_to_walk = $("#latest").width();
var interval_between_floater = 50; // distance in pixel between each floater
var distance_pop = distance_to_walk - 32; // replace 32 by the width of a floater
var step = 2; // the number pixel through by floater at each step
var number_floaters = 8; // number of floater to display
var delay_between_frame = 10;
var duration_animation = 1000 * 10 * 3;

$('.floater').each(function(){
    $(this).css('left',distance_pop + 'px') ;
});

var i=0;
var number_frames = duration_animation/ (delay_between_frame + 2);
var cpt_frames = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){

$('.floater').each(function(){
   $(this).css('left', ($(this).offset().left-2) + "px");
    if(!$(this).hasClass("spawned") &&
       ($(this).offset().left + $(this).width() + interval_between_floater)  <= distance_pop ){
       // If a spawner can spawn another floater
       if( i < number_floaters){
          //If the maximum floaters is not good
          var new_floater = $(this).clone();

          $("#latest").append( new_floater );
          // Move the floater at the beginning
          $(new_floater).css('left', distance_pop + 'px');
          // Add this to disable the spawning with this floater
          $(this).addClass("spawned");
          i++;
      }
    }
    if( $(this).offset().left <= -($(this).width())){
        // If the floater is out of screen
        $(this).css("left", distance_pop + 'px');
    }
});

cpt_frames++;

if(cpt_frames >= number_frames){
  console.log("fin");
  clearInterval(interval);
  return;
}
}, delay_between_frame);
```

You can test the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/MZhDh/3/)

EDIT :

New example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/MZhDh/10/).

EDIT 2 :

The example with the relative postion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MZhDh/17/)

Comment: That's nearly exactly what I want! Could you cause each div to respawn at the beginning again and I'll close this off and give you the bounty.

Comment: ok I edit this in few times. Do you want a random spawing as you say ?

Comment: Hi Charles. Not random, just when a box leaves on the left, it starts again at the right, so basically we end up with a scrolling marque of boxes.

Comment: I notice that the floaters are absolutely positioned, and as it is this doesn't work well for higher resolutions. How can I changed the CSS so that the floaters always stay and scroll in their container? I have tried messing with the absolute and relative properties but to no effect :(

Comment: I figured it out! I changed all the .offset() to .position() as I needed them to be relative to the #latest container.

Comment: I find an alternative with relative http://jsfiddle.net/MZhDh/17/. I don't like but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It could probably use some improvements but you could do something like this to create a marquee that moves from right to left:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.floater').css('opacity', '0');
    var randomNumber = 0;
    var $flot = null;
    floaters();
})

function floaters($current) {
    if ($current != null) $flot = $current;
    else $flot = $('.floater');

    $flot.each(function() {
        randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 320); /*Random number from 1 to 320*/
        $(this).css("left", randomNum);
        $(this).animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 5000
        });
        $(this).animate({
            'left': '0'
        }, 10000 * (randomNum / 320), 'linear', function() {
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.0');
            floaters($(this));
        });
    })
}
```

I updated your CSS to contain absolute positions because technically, all boxes need to finish at the same location.

```
#latest {
    background:#000000;
    height:35px;
    width:320px;
    position:absolute;
}
.floater {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
}
```

Basically you want to find all the floating boxes, begin the animate function but have a set time relative to where they began.  When a float box does reach it's destination, the process repeats but passes itself to the function to reassign its starting position.  This script doesn't accommodate for collisions of floating boxes although that could be added.

http://jsfiddle.net/r0m4n/Y73TZ/4/